# Cannot get Dynamic Parameters to show in built in Crystal Report Viewer in third party software

Tags: crystal-reports

Its likely the restrictions of the software I'm using but thought I'd see if anyone can help!

I've created a dynamic parameter to choose between different stock warehouses. Its works fine in SAP Crystal Reports (see image) I get the dropdown and its works as it should.

However when I run it in the third party software it only give the option to enter a text field (no dropdown).

Has anyone else experienced something like this? Anything I can change in crystal to force it to provide a dropdown?

[Working in SAP Crystal Reports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBNJf.png)

[Not working in third party software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6dIG.png)

Comment: Do you know what version of crystal reports the 3rd party software was designed to use?  I have an environment where my 3rd party ERP system was designed using CR XI, but I design all of the reports using Crystal Reports 2016.  Since my designer is a much newer version than the ERP system, there are features available in my designer that are not supported in the older version used in my ERP system.  If this is the case for you as well, sadly, there is no solution.  Rather you have to learn to avoid the features that are not supported in the third party software.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I'm afraid not, i've looked all over for a version on the third party. The software itself is pretty old so I wouldn't be surprised if it can't use the newer features. Nevermind! Would be fine if its was just me, but needed an easy way for my users. I think I'll just have to find a work around, probably outside of this ancient software!

Comment: You could always choose to use the report from outside your third party software system.    You just need to install the right version of the Crystal Report Viewer.  I personally don't have a lot of experience with the process, but I know its possible to make a crystal report into an executable file if you have the report viewer installed.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should switch to a different 3rd-party viewer.
See list of 3rd-party viewers [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#viewers).